# iPhone VPN to iTunes Home Sharing (Windows)

Tags: windows, itunes, vpn, iphone, bonjour

My goal is to set up a VPN on a Windows machine that contains my iTunes library then connect to that VPN with my iPhone for iTunes Home Sharing (over the VPN). I have read that this can be set up if the iTunes library is on a Mac (via Network Beacon or other utilities). I can't find anyone who has had success on a Windows machine, though.

In my thinking, there are two options (aside from buying a Mac or *emulating* Mac, per wizlog):

1.) Existing utility that sets this up for me and is compatible with iPhone (Hamachi is NOT compatible with iPhone VPN)

2.) Manually configure a VPN to allow Bonjour multicast (can't find any information on what is required for this)

FYI my router is a Linksys WRT54GL running Tomato 1.28

*Note* question is related to [this](https://superuser.com/q/158210/81403)

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions.

Comment: interesting comment.  Stack Overflow says, "Post on SuperUser and ServerFault."  ServerFault says, "This belongs on SuperUser."  SuperUser says, "please don't cross-post questions"!  haha, circular references!  Is there a way to migrate a post if someone says it doesn't belong on that site?

Comment: Yeah, well, StackOverflow is known for migrating *absolute crap* in some cases, (not saying that this is), not related to the target site, or some things that should be closed and deleted even before migartion. This is probably the best place for this question (unless you don't get an answer, in which case you could ask on AskDifferent...our Apple sister site ;))

Comment: The point is that you should only post on one site, and you should choose the appropriate site before you post. This question is reasonable on SU. You posted it in two places, then Server Fault migrated it here because it was off-topic there. So, basically, just post in one place and you'll be fine.

Comment: alright, thanks!  now... I just need an answer!  haha